# Редирект в htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Нужно настроить редирект /directory1/*/page_name на /directory2/page_name в htaccess. Подскажите как это реализовать.

Буду рад, если также подскажите обучающий материал по .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule directory1\/[.+]\/page_name directory2/page_name
</IfModule>
```

mod_rewrite при этом должен быть конечно же включен